# If $2\leq p\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f\in\mathbb{Q}_p[x]$, then ($f$ has infinitely many roots $\Leftrightarrow$ $f=0$) $\Leftrightarrow$ $p$ prime power.

Tags: polynomials, p-adic-number-theory

Is the statement below true?

If $2\leq p\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f\in\mathbb{Q}_p[x]$, then ($f$ has infinitely many roots $\Leftrightarrow$ $f=0$) $\Leftrightarrow$ $p$ prime power.

Comment: The system does allow you to post your question; the problem is you didn't post your question. I have edited your post to actually post the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $s$ is not a prime power, then the ring of $s$-adic integers $\Bbb Z_s$ is isomorphic to a ring $\Bbb Z_\sigma\oplus\Bbb Z_\tau$, where $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are integers with $1<\sigma<s$ and $1<\tau<s$. Take the polynomial $f(X)=(1,0)X\in\Bbb Z_\sigma\oplus\Bbb Z_\tau$, then $f(0,a)=0$ for all the infinitely many $a\in\Bbb Z_\tau$.

And of course if $s=p^m$ for a prime $p$, then $\Bbb Z_s=\Bbb Z_p$, and the parenthesized equivalence is true.

Comment: "And of course if $s=p^m$ for a prime $p$, then $\mathbb{Z}_s=\mathbb{Z}_p$, and the parenthesized equivalence is true." Why is this clear? Is this true in every domain?

Comment: Ah, I see, it's true in every field (can be proven by induction on the degree) and thus it's true in every domain (just go to the field of fractions).

Comment: I don’t look at it that way. It’s just that a sequence is $s$-adically Cauchy if and only if it’s $p$-adically Cauchy.

Comment: You mean to see that $\mathbb{Z}_s$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are isomorphic? That's not what I meant, I was talking about the "$f$ has infinitely many roots iff $f=0$" part. I know that this follows from the fundamental theorem of algebra for the reals but I wasn't sure about $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: It doesn’t follow from the FTA, but rather from the fact that a polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients in a (commutative) field has at most $n$ roots, and you show this with Euclidean division and uniqueness of factorization in the polynomial ring. Since $\Bbb Z_p$ is an integral domain (embeddable into a field), the fact applies.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I meant. One doesn't need FTA.